# Templated type conversion operator =

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion

I'm trying to get a class R type T to be convertible to R type S and visa-versa.  The operator = conversion works ok with a simple assignment, but when it try to use it in an initializer, it fails.  Why?

```
#include <array>

template<class T>
class Rectangle
{
public :

    Rectangle(T l, T t, T r, T b) : x1(l), y1(t), x2(r), y2(b) 
    {

    }

    template<class S>
    Rectangle<T> & operator = (Rectangle<S> const & o)
    {
        x1 = static_cast<T>(o.x1);
        y1 = static_cast<T>(o.y1);
        x2 = static_cast<T>(o.x2);
        y2 = static_cast<T>(o.y2);

        return *this;
    }

    T x1, y1, x2, y2;
};

int main(void)
{
    auto foo = Rectangle<float>(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f);
    auto bar = Rectangle<double>(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);

    {
        foo = bar; // Converts, ok.
    }

    {
        auto arr = std::array<Rectangle<float>, 2>() = {{ 
            foo, 
            bar // Error - no appropriate default constuctor
        }};
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Edit:  I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here. First:

```
auto arr = std::array<Rectangle<float>, 2>() = ...
```

`Rectangle<T>` isn't default-constructible, so the `()` won't work. Given the second `=` anyway, I suspect this was just a typo. Once you fix that:

```
    auto arr = std::array<Rectangle<float>, 2>{{ 
        foo, 
        bar // Still error
    }};
```

Now, you have a assignment operator, but we're not assigning. We're constructing. So what you need is a constructor:

```
template <class S>
Rectangle(Rectangle<S> const& o)
    : x1(o.x1)
    , y1(o.y1)
    , x2(o.x2)
    , y2(o.y2)
{ }
```

Comment: I see your answer is *probably* correct and that perhaps the fact I'm using Visual Studio 2013 is the problem here.   I tried the constructor and it made no difference.  Removing the = is a syntax error ("expected a ;").

Comment: @Robinson Having two `=`s is clearly wrong. You have `auto x = T() = {{...}};`, which is trying to assign to an rvalue. It may be that VS13 just doesn't support brace initialization correctly? I'm not familiar with its limitations.

Comment: I don't think it does, no.  I have to initialise std::array like that.  I'll try with 2015 later.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is conversion "copy" constructor

```
template<class S>
Rectangle(Rectangle<S> const & o) : Rectangle(o.x1, o.x2, o.y1, o.y2)
```

When you write code like:

```
A x = {a};
```

You are really using constructor (with `a` as argument), not an assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

To make class A convertable to class B you need to define a conversion operator, not an assignment operator.

Example:

```
operator B() {
   B b;
   b.populate_from(this);
   return b;
}
```